# how can I do a string check inside a string in php?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how can I do a string check inside a string?

for example:

```
$variable = "Pensioner (other)";
```

If I want to check whether $variable contain the word 'Pensioner', how can I do it in PHP? I have tried the following code in php, but it's always return me false :(

```
$pos = strripos($variable,"Pensioner");
if($pos) echo "found one";
else echo "not found";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

You are using the reverse function `strripos`, you need to use `stripos`.

```
if (stripos($variable, "Pensioner") !== FALSE){
  // found
}
else{
 // not found
}
```

This should do:

```
if (strripos($variable, "Pensioner") !== FALSE){
  // found
}
else{
 // not found
}
```

The **strict type comparison (`!==`)** is important there when using [`strpos/stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: yes, I do tried using your provided code, but the result still the same, it will not show me the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

In the manual, [the example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) uses  a === for comparison. [The === operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) also compares the type of both operands. To check for 'not equal', use !==.

Your search target 'Pensioner' is at position 0, and the function returns 0, which equal false, hence `if ($pos)` failed all the time. To correct that, your code should read:

```
$pos = strripos($variable,"Pensioner");
if($pos !== false) echo "found one";
      else echo "not found";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with strripos and its siblings is that they return the *position* of the substring found. So if the substring you're searching happens to be at the start, it returns 0 which in a boolean test is false.

Use:

```
if ( $pos !== FALSE ) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable = 'Pensioner (other)';
$pos = strripos($variable, 'pensioner');

if ($pos !== FALSE) {
 echo 'found one';
} else {
 echo 'not found';
}
```

^ Works for me. Note that `strripos()` is case insensitive. If you wanted it to be a case-sensitive search, use `strrpos()` instead.